# data comparison between two text files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to programming and I need help. I know similar questions have been asked before but all what I found was data match between two txt files only.

I have two txt files (Aout.txt and Bout.txt) that i created using python to extract data from log files.

both Aout.txt and Bout.txt has similar data and need to cross this information and get the finaloutput.txt

here is sample of Aout.txt:

```
----------------------------

Thu Nov  2 15:53:19 2017 Info: New SMTP ICID 111111 interface (1.2.3.4) address 5.6.7.8 reverse dns host  verified yes
Thu Nov  2 15:53:21 2017 Info: MID 22222 ICID 111111 From: <example@test.com>
Thu Nov  2 15:53:23 2017 Info: MID 22222 ICID 111111 RID 0 To: <receive@acme.com>
Thu Nov  2 15:53:27 2017 Info: MID 22222 Subject 'TEST'


----------------------------
```

sample of Bout.txt:

```
----------------------------

1509654863.891601 info msg 22222 : bytes 332 from <example@test.com> qp 0 uid 0
1509654864.031506 starting delivery 654321: msg 22222 to remote receive@acme.com
1509654864.863334 delivery 654321: success: 9.8.7.6_accepted_message./Remote_host_said:_250_2.6.0_<123@mailserver.com>_[InternalId=1122334455]_Queued_mail_for_delivery/


----------------------------
```

I need to check if msg 'Number' from Bout.txt is the same as MID 'Number' from Aout.txt. If they match then I need to check if there is delivery success for that message from Bout.txt. If true then finaloutpout will be the first line from Aout.txt for the same message

finaloutput.txt:

```
----------------------------

Thu Nov  2 15:53:19 2017 Info: New SMTP ICID 111111 interface (1.2.3.4) address 5.6.7.8 reverse dns host  verified yes

----------------------------
```

and If I can get

```
address 5.6.7.8
```

by itself in different output file. This would be perfect.

I did count of successful output messages and they were over 4600 and increasing.

Any help will be appreciated and I'm using python 2.7

Thanks.

I used these codes for extracting the Aout.txt and Bout.txt

```
import os
import glob

indir="C:\\Users\\Mail Logs"
os.chdir(indir)
list_of_files = glob.glob('*')           # create the list of file
FO = open("C:\\Users\\Result\\Aout.txt", 'w')
file_list=[]
for file_name in list_of_files:
    file_list.append(file_name)



for file_name in file_list:
  FI = open(file_name, 'r')

  for line in FI:
      if 'New SMTP ICID' in line:
           FO.write('\n')
           FO.write("\n----------------------------\n")
           FO.write('\n')
           FO.write(line)
      elif 'From:' in line:
           FO.write(line)
      elif 'To:' in line:
           FO.write(line)
      elif 'Subject' in line:
           FO.write(line)     



  FI.close()
FO.close()
```

and for Bout.txt

```
import os
import glob

indir="C:\\Users\\Qmail logs"
os.chdir(indir)
list_of_files = glob.glob('*')           # create the list of file
FO = open("C:\\Users\\Result\\Bout.txt", 'w')

file_list=[]
for file_name in list_of_files:
    file_list.append(file_name)


for file_name in file_list:
  FI = open(file_name, 'r')

  for line in FI:
      if 'info msg' in line:
           FO.write('\n')
           FO.write("\n----------------------------\n")
           FO.write('\n')
           FO.write(line)
      elif 'starting delivery' in line:
           FO.write(line)
      elif 'success' in line:
           FO.write(line)
      elif 'deferral' in line:
           FO.write(line)   
      elif 'failure' in line:
           FO.write(line)  


  FI.close()
FO.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain what have you tried and what's not working? Also, code snippets will be good and help us, help you.

Comment: can you tell us, are your txt files containing blocks like you showed here? Presumably you have multiple blocks in both A and B following the same format ? i.e. each block will have a title line and subsquent MID details (A),  and the same applies in B as well. there are patterns that we could make use of, but you have to confirm the details.

Comment: that being said, I also think what Amit has suggested was more constructive to you and other guys who may bump into the same problem. if you could show us what you have tried (you are new to programming overall), we could provide more details as in how you could improve on your own.

Comment: Hi Amit and Stucash,
I'm still trying to tackle this issue and not sure were even to start as I'm still trying to learn programming. That's why I'm asking about any hints, help guidance in order for me to figure out a solution. I have updated my question with the codes I used to extract Aout.txt and Bout.txt as there was way more unwanted info in the original log data. and there is a pattern where every new message start with "New SMTP ICID" for Aout.txt and "info msg" for Bout.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all you can immediately start to break your problem down into several smaller, more manageable chunks of work. You have a number of assumed operations in this.

You will be searching, comparing, extracting and writing to disk. Unfortunately based on the information provided searching will be the most inefficient part of the solution.

You will have to analyse two sets of data. You should start by writing functions to handle this rather than attack the problem head on. Divide and conquer!

```
def scan_log_file(file, search_term):
    # Scan over the given input and determine if the search term is present
    ....
    # Your implementation here

def extract_host(data):
    # Return your host address from the input data
    ...
    return address

def extract_message_id(data):
    # given a line that may include the message id, search it
    ...
    return message_id

def write_file_data(filename, data):
    # Here you append data to the file you want
    ...
```

So getting to actually searching the file data. You could use regular expressions to achieve this nicely. If you are not familiar with them, now is a great time to get to know them. They are a super useful in your tool belt.

For example you can look up your message ids using something like so:

```
import re
results = re.search('address (\d\.\d.\d.\d)')
results.group(0) # get the first accepted group, i.e the host address
```

You can iterate over your first data set, extract message ids, then perform a scan on your second set, extract the host address, write the comparison of the first set to the file finaloutput.txt, write the host address to file host_results.txt.

That's a fairly naive implementation. It should however get you started. I am not sure how large your files may eventually become but I would also suggest looking into generators for reading the log files bit by bit in smaller streams rather than bulk loading huge data sets into memory

But much like the existing comments. There could be optimizations made from assumptions about your data. Is it predictable? Does it need to be transformed, formatted, etc...

I would suggest padding out your question a little bit to get a better idea of the scope and particulars of the problem

Comment: Hi kmjb, thanks for the helping notes. the data files are not that large. The original size of raw log files for Aout.txt is about 10M and after running my code I got about 2 M of data in my output "Aout.txt". for the second out put"Bout" the raw logs are about 3 M where the results is about 2 M (not much difference).  Unfortunately the logs to get both info I'm looking for has to come from two different log setting in the mail server and even going to debug level in one of the settings will not give the full information in one file that's why I have this more complicated issue.

Comment: its an old mail server I'm trying to gather data from and to route its traffic to another server. The mail server has no gui which makes things more difficult.